# Creating a folder if it does not exists - "Item already exists"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a folder using PowerShell if it does not exists so I did :

```
$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$TARGETDIR = "$DOCDIR\MatchedLog"
if(!(Test-Path -Path MatchedLog )){
   New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $DOCDIR\MatchedLog
}
```

This is giving me error that the folder already exists, which it does but It shouldn't be trying to create it.

I am not sure what's wrong here

> New-Item : Item with specified name C:\Users\l\Documents\MatchedLog already exists. At C:\Users\l\Documents\Powershell\email.ps1:4 char:13
>   +     New-Item <<<<  -ItemType directory -Path $DOCDIR\MatchedLog
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\Users\l....ents\MatchedLog:String) [New-Item], IOException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand`

Comment: try this:New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Path\That\May\Or\May\Not\Exist

Answer (score 122):

I was not even concentrating, here is how to do it

```
$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$TARGETDIR = '$DOCDIR\MatchedLog'
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}
```

Comment: The value of $TARGETDIR should be in double quotes, string expansion is disabled inside single and you'll end up with invalid path

Comment: Wouldn't an existing file of the same name as the folder you are trying to create match Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR too?  (Thinking of adding "-pathType container")

Answer (score 64):

With New-Item you can add the Force parameter

```
New-Item -Force -ItemType directory -Path foo
```

Or the ErrorAction parameter

```
New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -ItemType directory -Path foo
```

Comment: JFI "-ErrorAction Ignore" not supported in PowerShell 2

Comment: An answer to a different question.

Comment: To create the item without console printout: New-Item -Force -ItemType directory -Path D:\yourpath\1 | Out-Null

Answer (score 21):

Alternative syntax using the `-Not` operator and depending on your preference for readability:

```
if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR ) )
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, even simpler: 

if (-Not (Get-Item C:\Temp))
{ 
New-Item -ItemType dir "C:\Temp"
}

Assuming you want to create C:\Temp.

Comment: '(if((test-path \\$ServersList\d$\install\foldertocopy -eq $false) { New-Item -force -ErrorAction Ignore -ItemType directory -Path \\$ServersList\d$\install\foldertocopy)|out-null'